# How to redirect output of a program only if it succeeded?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

When one of my programs returns with a non-zero exit code, I want to avoid redirecting its output. Is this possible, and, if so, how do I do this?

My failed attempt:

```
echo foo > file
false | cat > file
```

this results in `file` being empty. The behaviour I want is to only adjust `file` when the program succeeds.

I also wonder whether it is possible do only update a file if the output is non-empty, without using multiple files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
out=$(some_command) && echo "$out" > outfile
```

`echo "$out" > outfile` will execute only when `some_command` succeeds.

Comment: is it also possible to check for empty output in a similar way? What is the difference between `$(...)` and `\`...\``?

Comment: `$(...)` is newer and preferred way of command substitution. We can check non-empty value as well like: **`out=$(some_command) && [[ -n "$out" ]] && echo "$out" > outfile`**

Comment: Note: If the output of some_command is huge, you may want to `t=$(mktemp); some_command >$t && cat $t > outfile; rm -f $t`

Comment: Yes `mktemp` is the way to go for handling huge output.

Comment: And just to scope the issue a bit, shell redirection and pipes happen before your command is even run.  This is why your original attempts couldn't work;  your output file was gone before your program ever ran.

Comment: I am continuously amazed at how poorly designed shell scripting is

Comment: NB: double quotes in echo "$out" are mandatory if output contains newlines

Answer (score 0):

if avoiding empty file creation and deletion is not essential, maybe it is a good replacement

```
false > file || rm -f file
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all the cases: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287865/