# How to stop redirecting stdout when one program fails in the chain?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In the normal case, this would output file.out

```
$ program1 | program2 | program3 > file.out
```

But what happens if `program1` fails?  What happens is that the rest of the chain still fires and the file is created

```
$ false | echo worked > file.out
$ cat file.out
worked
```

I don't want the file to appear.

There is another [SO article about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424456/how-to-redirect-output-of-a-program-only-if-it-succeeded) that suggests adding an OR clause, like so:

```
$ false | echo worked > file.out || rm file.out
ls file.out
file.out
```

This doesn't work.  The second command fires and counts as a success.

That same SO article also suggests using a double ampersand, like so:

```
$ program1 && program2 && program2 > file.out
```

That doesn't work entirely.  In my case program2 is expecting output from the stdout, so this chain ends up hanging because the chain is not stopping.  You can see how this works with a trivial example:

```
$ echo something > stuff.txt
$ cat stuff.txt && false > file.out
something
$ cat file.out
```

It's not redirecting the output.

But, even worse, when things are happy, it doesn't work either.

```
$ echo something > stuff.txt
$ cat stuff.txt && true > file.out
something
$ cat file.out
```

In this case, file.out is created and it's blank.  Uh-Oh.

---

I accepted an answer below.  Calling `set -o pipefail` was the tip that I needed.  In my real situation, I'm using a Makefile.  To adapt this to work in a Makefile, I added this to the top of the file

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

And then to my target:

```
target:
    @set -o pipefail; program1 | program2 | program3 > $@
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exit when one process in pipe fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684119/exit-when-one-process-in-pipe-fails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When bash executes `program1 | program2 | program3 > file.out`, it creates `file.out` before program1 is started.  If you want to ensure that it is never created, you'll need to buffer the output (either in memory or in a temporary file).  I find the cleanest syntax for that is something like:

```
if v=$( set -o pipefail; program1 | program2 | program3 ); then 
    echo "$v" > file.out
fi
```

or (this has different semantics, ignoring the return value.  Depending on your use case, this may be acceptable):

```
v=$( program1 | program2 | program3 )
test -n "$v" && echo "$v" > file.out
```

If you're okay with creating the file and then deleting it, you can do

```
set -o pipefail
program1 | progam2 | program3 > file.out || rm file.out
```

If you don't want to use pipefail (eg, because you want the script to be portable), you can do something like:

```
{ { { program1 || echo . >&3; } | { program2 || echo . >&3;} | 
{ program3 || echo . >&3; } } 3>&1 >&4 | 
if grep -q .; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi ; } 4>&1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
false | echo worked > file.out || rm file.out
```

Above is the closest to what you want; if you turn on the `pipefail` option, it'll work. Like

```
$ set -o pipefail
$ false | echo foo > file || rm -f file
$ ls file
ls: cannot access 'file': No such file or directory
```

Concerning the exit status of a pipeline, and `pipefail`'s effect on it, the manual says

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command, unless the pipefail option is enabled.
>          If pipefail is enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with
>          a  non-zero  status,  or zero if all commands exit successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your commands in functions and you may add any error handling you want:

```
f_program1()
{
  program1 || pkill -f program2
}

f_program2()
{
  program2 || pkill -f program3
}

f_program3()
{
  program3
}

f_program1 | f_program2 | f_program3 > file.out
```

I'm not sure that `pkill` is your best error handling strategy, so treat it as a placeholder for the sake of the argument that functions can make your troubles go away.

Comment: just a side-note: the use of the `function` keyword is optional, and it's actually preferable to omit it (making your scripts more portable)